# Find a group of file extensions but stop when I hit a different file extension

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am working on a project in Visual Basic 2010 that takes a folder directory and searches all the files in it, by the specified file extensions provided via a `TextBox`. This works, I can search and find all the specified files using this line of code.

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(des, ext)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, subfol & My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(foundFile))
Next
```

Although this code works, I want the `For Each` loop to stop when it hits a different file extension provided by a different `TextBox`. The files I usually search for are .3ds extension, but I want the for each method to stop when it hits a .error.3ds file extension. Is this possible?

When it hits this .error.3ds file, I want it to take all the files it found up to this point, make a new directory and move them to that directory, then continue on AFTER skipping the .error.3ds file. And do this over and over again until there are no more files to be moved. I also have the move method figured out, just I need the `For Each` loop to break when it hits a .error.3ds file.

Comment: Um... You have the filename in `foundFile`. Check the extension of that file, and do whatever you want with it between `For` and `Next`. What's the specific problem you're having doing so?

Comment: You're right I do have the filename in foundfile. The problem I am having is any file with the extension .3ds is included in "foundfile" INCLUDING the .error.3ds, how do I tell my application to depict between *.error.3ds and just *.3ds ? I want it to read all the .3ds files UP TO .error.3ds then stop and take those files and move them to a new directory that it creates? How do I do this without moving every file in the folder? I've already played around with this a little bit and everything I do, I end up moving all the files

Comment: `System.String.IndexOf()` or `System.String.Contains()` doesn't work for you to locate `error.3ds` in `foundFile`?

Comment: To be honest I didn't try those, I was trying IF statements lol sorry still kinda noobish to coding. Thanks though for the help I'll give these a try tomorrow.